# Markov Processes - question about an inference equation

Tags: markov-process

in the following link, time 19:49:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOWBb0mqENw&list=PLdAoL1zKcqTXFJniO3Tqqn6xMBBL07EDc&index=2

there is the following equation:

$P(S_{t+k}|S_t)$ = $\sum_{s_{t+1}...s_{t+k-1}}$$\prod_{i=1}^{k}(P(S_{t+i}|S_{t+i-1}))$

now, there are several things I do not understand about this equation. except for direct answers, I would ***also*** like to know how did you know this is the answer from reading the equation (in contrast to answering just from older knowledge). differently asked, how could I know that this is the answer?

1. what question is the equation actually answering? if we take whether as an example, is it "what is the probability of getting an exact state (rain, lets say) k days from now given the whether today?" or "what is the probability for each outcome (rain, fog, snow, sun) given the wehther today?"?.
2. what is going on in the right hand side in terms of the sum? I mean, we are summing a multiplication chain that is identical each time (since i always starts at 1, and always ends in the same number, k, which is defined in the left hand side). so instead of using the sum sign, will it not be simpler to just multiply the multiplication chain by k-2?

Answer (score 0):

1. Neither of your answers, actually, $P(S_{t_k}|S_t)$ is even more general. It is mathematically a function of two variables so it answers the question "What is the probability for each outcome (rain, fog, snow, sun) given that today's outcome can be (rain, fog, snow, sun)?".
2. I don't really understand your question. The value of $P(S_{t+i}|S_{t+i-1})$ varies for each $t$ so what you suggest is incorrect. You can make the RHS more explicit by actually expanding the sum and the multiplication, and if it helps you use actual values of $t$. It will become clear why it is written this way. You should find that the sum is an instance of *marginalization*, the process of summing over unobserved outcomes in order to "ignore" them in a principled way; and that the product comes from the fact that the model is a Markov chain where each outcome only depends on the previous one.

Make sure you understand all the notations!

Comment: i know that the value of P(S_t+i|S_t+i-1) change for every e - but the value of the complete capital pi (the whole product) stays the same each time, that is what bothering me!

Comment: "the whole product stays the same": in general, it should not stay the same. Do you agree that each "whole product" is a particular case where you set $S_{t+1}, ..., S_{t+k-1}$ to all the possible combinations of outcomes? Then, do you also agree that if the whole product stays the same, it means that your outcomes do not matter (regardless of whether it rains or is sunny, we will predict the same thing)?